# Parabola and straight line

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

If $m$ varies then find the range of $c$ for which the line $y=mx + c$ touches the parabola $y^2 = 8(x+2)$ .

**My Attempt:**

Put the value $y = mx + c$ in the parabola equation and then done $\Delta = 0$ or $\Delta >0$

I am getting $16/(m^2 + 8m) >0$

But in this, how do I neglect $m$?

Comment: What's the meaning of the word 'touches' here?

Comment: @G-man Possible? It's more like carbon copy duplicate.

Comment: @G-man previous one was my wrong post

Comment: @RobertSoupe you probably already know that the comment is sytem-generated.

Comment: @G-man I already know it but I keep forgetting it. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is asking you to find for every $m$ the range of $c$ such that the line touches the parabola. Substituting $x=\frac{y-c}{m}$ in the parabola equation we get
$$my^2-8y-16m+8c=0$$
so
$$\Delta=64+64m^2-32mc=32(2m^2-mc+2).$$
You need  $\Delta \ge0$, hence $2m^2-mc+2\ge0$, that is equivalent to:
$$c\le 2m+\frac{2}{m}$$
when $m>0$
$$c\ge 2m+\frac{2}{m}$$
when $m<0$.

Comment: IMHO for each $m$ there exists at most one value $c(m)$ such that the described line touches (but does not cross) the parabola.

Comment: I assumed that touches here means just intersects. Indeed the poroblem ask for a range for $c$

Comment: @mrprottolo  yes touches here means intersects

Comment: Thank you very much for helping

Comment: As I understand it, the range to find is a set of $c(m)$, collected for all such $m$, for which the tangent line with slope $m$ exists (and for example a tangent line does not exists for $m=0$).

Comment: ...but possibly I'm wrong — then the range of $c$ to be found is an image of the parabola being projected onto the $Y$ axis along the direction given by the slope $m$.